# elasticsearch: combine text match and array contains

Tags: elasticsearch

We have documents in `elastic` saved in the following structure:

```
{
    ...
    name: "name",
    ancestors: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
    ...
}
```

I want to create a search query that searches for `name: "some name"` `AND` `ancestors contains "id1"`.

I've tried many queries but none seems to work, or return the desired result. If it's of any help, this combined query should only return one entry every time.

Some of the queries I've tried are the following:

```
filtered: {
    query: {
        query_string: {
            query: "name:name"
        },
        term: {
            ancestors: "id1"
        }
    }
}
```

__

```
match: {
    name: "name",
    ancestors: "id1"
},
defaultOperator: 'AND'
```

__

```
bool: {
   must: { term: { name: "name" }},
   filter: {
       term: { ancestors: "id1" }
   }
}
```

The mappings are the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "mappings": {
      "entry": {
        "properties": {
          "ancestors": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We haven't changed the default mappings, that's why `ancestors` is of type `string`, but I don't think this makes any difference

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: I added some of them in the question

Comment: Also share the mapping.. `GET/index/type/_mapping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        { 
         "query_string": { 
            "default_field": "name", 
           "query": "stripe AND 1" 
         } 
      },
        {
           "match": {
              "ancestors": "id1"
             }
          }
        ]
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: returns multiple docs. Doesn't seem to apply an `AND` operator

Comment: `must` will always apply `AND` between multiple queries. May be you have multiple docs which fulfill this condition.

Comment: The ancestors may contain the same id, but an ancestor cannot contain many children with same name. That's why there must always be one entry as a result

Comment: What values of `name` are you getting in result. Can you mention few? May be this is because `name` field is `analyzed`.

Comment: I'm searching for `"Stripe 80"` and getting `"Stripe 80"` and `"Stripe 2"` among others. The common in all results is that they contain the id in `ancestors`

Comment: Yeaah.. All of the names carry same term `Stripe`. Since `name` field is analyzed . So it gets tokenized into `Stripe`, `80`. and that's why `match` query is resulting in "Stripe 80", "Stripe 2" in output. If you want exact match , you can make your `name` field `not_analyzed` and use '`term` query instead of `match`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133278/discussion-between-richa-and-xeniasis).

Comment: changed it to `term` but still getting all those unwanted stripes